# HTTP 400 and 500 error messages

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

when I run my application, I'm having a HTTP error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /ProjectName/

This is the URL of my project:

> localhost:8080/Initiation1/

When I type this string to the address bar:

> localhost:8080/Initiation1/CarteIdentite

, I'm having this HTTP 500 error message:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class ca.web.CarteIdentite
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ca.web.CarteIdentite
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my servlet code:

```
package ca.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CarteIdentite
 */
@WebServlet("/CarteIdentite")
public class CarteIdentite extends HttpServlet
{
    // paramètres d’instance
    private String defaultNom = null;
    private String defaultAge = null;
    private String defaultCourriel = null;
    //init
    public void init()
    {
    // on récupère les paramètres d’initialisation de la servlet
    ServletConfig config = getServletConfig();
    defaultNom = config.getInitParameter("defaultNom");
        if(defaultNom==null)
        {
            defaultNom="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        }
        defaultAge = config.getInitParameter("defaultAge");
        if(defaultAge==null)
        {
            defaultAge="AAA";
        }
        defaultCourriel = config.getInitParameter("defaultCourriel");
        if(defaultCourriel==null)
        {
            defaultCourriel="XXXXXX@XXXXXXXX.XX";
        }
    }
    //GET
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws
    IOException, ServletException
    {
    // on récupère les paramètres du formulaire

    String nom = request.getParameter("txtNom");
    if (nom == null)
    {
        nom = defaultNom;
    }
    String age = request.getParameter("txtAge");
    if (age == null)
    {
        age = defaultAge;
    }
    String courriel = request.getParameter("txtCourriel");
    if (courriel == null)
    {
        courriel = defaultCourriel;
    }
    // on affiche le formulaire
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.println
    (
        "<html>"+
        "<head>"+
        "<title>Carte d’identité</title>"+
        "</head>"+
        "<body>"+
        "<center>"+
        "<h2>Carte d’identité</h2>"+
        "<form action=’’ method=’post’>"+
        "<table>"+
        "<tr>"+
        "<td>Nom:</td>"+
        "<td><input name=’txtNom’ value=’"+nom+"’ type=’text’ size=’30’></td>"+
        "</tr>"+
        "<tr>"+
        "<td>Age:</td>"+
        "<td><input name=’txtAge’ value=’"+ age +"’ type=’text’ size=’3’></td>"+
        "</tr>"+
        "<tr>"+
        "<td>Courriel:</td>"+
        "<td><input name=’txtCourriel’ value=’"+courriel+"’ type=’text’ size=’30’></td>"+
        "</tr>"+
        "</table>"+
        "<table>"+
        "<tr>"+
        "<td><input type=’submit’ value=’Envoyer’></td>"+
        "<td><input type=’reset’ value=’Effacer’></td>"+
        "</tr>"+
        "</table>"+
        "</form>"+
        "</center>"+
        "</body>"+
        "</html>"       
    );
    }
    /**
    * @param request la requête HTTP du client
    * @param response la réponse HTTP qu’on va construire
    */
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
    //on passe la main au GET
    doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

This is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CarteIdentite</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ca.web.CarteIdentite</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
            <param-name>defaultNom</param-name>
            <param-value>inconnu</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
            <param-name>defaultAge</param-name>
            <param-value>XXX</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
            <param-name>defaultCourriel</param-name>
            <param-value>inconnu</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CarteIdentite</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CarteIdentite</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is my project structure:

[image: project structure]

Comment: Hi all,

I don't have the WEB-INF/classes folder in the project structure.
Also, when I right click on the project name, I don't have "Build Path"

Thank you.

Comment: You indeed don't see it in *Project Explorer*. You can however see it in *Navigator* view or just straight in the deploy location of the WAR file. This should however happen automatically. Did you rebuild the project, republish the server and restart the server?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Eclipse isn't treating `src` as a source folder. Try right clicking on it and choosing `Build Path` -> `Use as source folder`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the class `ca.web.CarteIdentite` has compiled correctly and made way into the WAR of your project (under WEB-INF/classes). If not, check/correct the project buildpath settings.